# How to send output to next input line?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, alias, macos

This my snippet `alias hst="history 1 -1 | cut -c 8- | uniq | fzf "`.
when I run `hst`
The output is

```bash
$ ~ hst
(the output from hst)
$
```

This is what I want

```bash
$ ~ hst
$ (the output from hst)
```

**Example**

```bash
$ ~ hst
vi .zshrc
$
```

should be

```bash
$ ~ hst
$ vi .zshrc
```

How to fix this?
(or enhance the script)

Comment: `$(hst)` or `eval $(hst)` would just directly execute whatever hst outputs; would skip a step.

Comment: @frabjous You'd need `eval "$(hst)"` in general. And you wouldn't get the opportunity to edit.

Comment: There are [several integrations of fzf with zsh](https://www.google.com/search?q=zsh+fzf+history) that may be more convenient that your home-grown one. I don't cite any specific one because I'm not familiar with any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add something to the shell input stack as if it was input by the user, you'd use `print -z`:

```
hst() {
  local cmd
  cmd=$(print -rNC1 -- ${(u)history} | fzf --read0 "$@") &&
    print -rz -- $cmd
}
```